# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed Laravel Validation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying the laravel validator but getting the error in the title.
This is the part of my code:

What i'm doing wrong?

```
  $data = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'number_1' => Rule::requiredIf(!$request->number_2 && !$request->number_3),
            'number_2' => Rule::requiredIf(!$request->number_1 && !$request->number_3),
            'number_3' => Rule::requiredIf(!$request->number_1 && !$request->number_2),
        ]);
```

I need those three numbers to be at least one required.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$data = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'number_1' => 'required_without_all:number_2,number_3',
            'number_2' => 'required_without_all:number_1,number_3',
            'number_3' => 'required_without_all:number_1,number_3',
        ]);
```

Check this link for more info https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-without-all